# Throttle Elasticsearch Watcher to one alert

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-watcher

How do I throttle an Elasticsearch Watcher to one alert per event. If an error shows in the logs the watcher will fire until it's acknowledged.

I only want alerts for new errors not a time throttle.

Answer (score 2):

I have found found a reasonable solution for this matter [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-setup-watcher-to-only-alert-on-new-messages/27330/2?u=thenmaptomyheartbeat).

I changed the interval of the watcher to `20s`. Then I added a filter for records that are older than `25s`.

It does only send one notification per record before it leaves that 5 second window. But I have noticed that this is isn't perfect. It does miss a couple of records but for the most part it works to a satisfactory level.

I added this just in case anyone needed it. If there is a better answer please let me know. I hope this helps.